# A not very obvious question about $\{h+tk\}$ sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, coprime

Let $h$ and $k$ be positive integers such that $\gcd(h,k)=1$. Let $A(h,k)$ be the sequence $$A(h,k)=\{h+kx|x=0,1,2,3,\cdots\}.$$
Let $S$ be a infinite subset of $A(h,k)$, prove that for each positive integer $n$, there is an integer in $A(h,k)$ that can be written as a product of more than $n$ different numbers from $S$.

---

I cannot have any insight for this question, so I use an example, $h=2,k=3$, then the sequence is $$2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50,53,56,59,62,\cdots$$
Since numbers in $S$ are also in $A(h,k)$, I try to find a number in $A(h,k)$ that is the product of other numbers in $A(h,k)$ but I failed. How can we solve this problem?

Source: Apostol Analytic Number Theory (Chapter 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I have just figured out the proof: It is because the sequence I write didn't have sufficiently much terms to make me realize the question's statement can be true.

For any number $y\in A(h,k)$, we always have $$y\equiv h\pmod k.$$

By Fermat little theorem, raising up to $\phi(k)$ power we have $$y^{\phi(k)}\equiv 1\pmod k$$

Or more generally, raising up to $m\phi(k)$ power for any positive integer $m$ we have $$y^{m\phi(k)}\equiv 1\pmod k\implies  y^{m\phi(k)+1}\equiv y\equiv h\pmod k$$
So for each positive integer $n$, let $m$ be a positive integer such that $m\phi(k)+1>n$, then we can choose $m\phi(k)+1$ different numbers from $S$, multiply them together, then the product write it as $N$, we have $$N\equiv y^{m\phi(k)+1}\equiv h\pmod k$$
Therefore there is positive integer $t$ such that $$N=h+tk\in A(h,k)$$
which completes the proof.